# How to change the print output/description of a class in dart?

Tags: dart

For example, the blow will output `Instance of 'Point'`. is it possible reformat it to sth like `Point(x: 0, y: 0)`?

```
class Point {
  final int x;
  final int y;

  Point(this.x, this.y);
}

void main() {
  final zero = Point(0, 0);
  print(zero); // Instance of 'Point'
}
```

In Python, there is `__repr__` and `__str__` . In Java, there is `toString`. In Swift/ObjC, there is `description`. What is the equivalent in dart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can overide the [toString](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Object/toString.html) method:

```
class Point {
  final int x;
  final int y;

  Point(this.x, this.y);

  @override
  String toString(){
    return "Point(x: $x, y: $y)";
  }
}

void main() {
  final zero = Point(0, 0);
  print(zero); // Point(x: 0, y: 0)
}
```

Which prints your wanted string.

Answer (score 2):

Dart has a [toString()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Object/toString.html) method as well, similar to Java!

```
class TestClass {

    String blah;
    TestClass(this.blah);

    @override
    String toString() {
        return blah;
    }
}

TestClass testClass = new TestClass("test");
print(testClass); //This will output 'test' as opposed to 'Instance of TestClass'
```